# php form submit counter

Tags: php, tracking, hitcounter

So I've made an extremely simple 4 page static webpage for this client with a quick contact form handled by php. Everything goes swimmingly.

Then the client comes to me and requests that he is able to see a counter of how many submits have been made. So he generally wants a counter for his form, Which is simple enough because I just add a counter for every successful email sent using the form and save it within some kind of data storage.

BUT...

the only way I can think to do it is have a separate user page with a simple box that has the number in it, that only the client can access.

I could do this... Save the counter in an xml file or a one table, one column, one row mySQL database.

But is there a better easier simpler way to do this??? Can I set up a link with Google analytics or something? Rather than making a single page with a number on it.

Comment: you can do this through a simple text file instead of xml page

Answer (score 1):

I suggest going with a separate page for the client to view counts.  You can use .htaccess to control the access to this page.  The main reason is looking forward to future client requests.  Most likely, they will then ask you to show counts for specified periods of time, counts per day/week/months, etc.  If you set up your page now, then you can have place to customize/extend.

As for storing the counter, I would suggest storing more than just the total.  Have a table where you'd store:

- date/time of form submission
- remote IP address (for possible future reference)
- content of the submitted form (if the client ever decides to want to see it)
- maybe event content of the email (if the client ever decides to want to resend it)

Then to display the totals, you'd just `select count(1) from that_table` with any required date/etc. grouping.